# How to use log_plays in playbook and config?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to understand and use `log_plays` so that I can separate out logs
per host (I have quite many hosts in `hosts.cfg` and I want each log in separate file).

I tried following: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html

Created the directory `/var/log/ansible/hosts`, added `community.general.log_plays` in the
playbook, tried `ANSIBLE_LOG_FOLDER` - didn't seem to pick.
Tried adding `[callback_log_plays]` section in `hosts.cfg` - threw some error and I had to remove it. But I am OK with the default `/var/log/ansible/hosts` directory.

I have commented out `log_path=` in `ansible.cfg`.

What else did I miss ?

My ansible version:

```
$ ansible-playbook --version 
ansible-playbook 2.9.21
  config file = /home/vyom/tstansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/vyom/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) [GCC 7.5.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad! I had more than 1 `callback_whitelist` line!! and in my case I had to also remove the `ansible.posix.` prefix and just say `log_plays`